# Google Sheets' SUMIF/Total Array Formula - Show totals only for rows with values

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, sumifs, array-formulas

My colleague and I are using the following array formulas to automatically add up five individual values received in a Google Sheet from a Google Form:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(G2:K2),ROW(G2:K200)),ROW(G2:K503),G2:200))

=ArrayFormula({"TOTAL";mmult(G2:K,sign(transpose(column(G2:K))))})
```

We were wondering if there is any way to tweak these formulas so that a number appears in the 'Total' column (in this case column L) *only* if values appear on that row. In short, we want to avoid a long column of 0s in the Total column in rows which haven't received any values/inputs from the Google Sheet yet.

Any suggestions would be really welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `IF` and check column A (in this example) and if empty then array formula will display nothing

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(G2:K2), ROW(G2:K200)), ROW(G2:K503), G2:200), ))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), {"TOTAL"; MMULT(G2:K, SIGN(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(G2:K))))}, ))
```

tweak `A1:A` based on in which row formula sits and based on what column is not empty

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion works perfectly, so we should be able to use that. I haven't managed to get the second ("TOTAL"; MMULT) formula to work yet, but I'll keep on tinkering with it. Thanks again.

Comment: @AWarde I could check if you would share a copy/dummy of your sheet

Comment: Thanks @player0.
I am able to use Google Sheets only through my workplace account, so I’m not able to share a ‘live’ dummy. However, here’s a link to a screengrab showing you the setup: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cprRw766KAh-YI4Za4Alit191vfolWNy/view?usp=sharing) 
As you can see, I’ve tweaked the first array formula you gave me so it sits within the ‘Total’ header rather than in cell L2 (in this case). However, I haven’t been able to get your second formula to work yet. I wouldn’t worry too much, as you’ve already made life a lot easier – and neater!
Cheers,
A.

Comment: in your first comment you telling that you didnt manage a 2nd formula (which is MMULT) an now in your last comment you telling that you still didnt manage 2nd formula (which is MMULT) but on picture you managed the MMULT formula. I am confused...

Comment: Sorry, @player0 - I wasn't being clear in my replies. When I mentioned "second" formula, I was referring to the list in my original question and the order of the formulas in your first reply. In that case, the "first" formula is the SUMIF option, which you successfully tweaked and which is the working version in the example I showed. The second formula in my original question/list is the mmult version, which hasn't worked for me yet. As I say, I'm more than happy with the first solution! Thanks again.

Comment: change **A1:A** to **A2:A** in your MMULT formula to get rid of that last zero at the end